Skype on Windows: how do I disable message previews?
In Message previews are a horrible privacy breach  in Skype:  when I open  the Skype window or am in a video call, all my conversations appear in the left-hand  pane, so that anybody who happens to  be in the room behind me can read them. Is it possible to disable this "feature"? Maybe by completely hiding the left-hand pane temporarily? Or, best, by just removing the message previews? I am OK with a programming  solution, such as AHK, Auto It, Powershell, Python or Perl. Skype version  I use  is 8.133.0.202 on Windows. I realize that I can just move the Skype window  to the left, for  the preview pane to go out of  monitor, but this does not solve the problem: when the  window is not  maximized, the text input  field at the bottom  is not visible, so I cannot type  a message.  I want to be able to use Skype normally: type a message or  make a video call even when my colleagues are in the room. Otherwise, the best  answer would be just not to use Skype.
